# Multiple file loading and embeddings with OpenAI

Tags: python, openai-api, embedding, faiss

I am trying to load a bunch of pdf files and query them using OpenAI APIs.

```
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
#from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
import pickle
import os


print("Loading data...")
pdf_folder_path = "content/"
print(os.listdir(pdf_folder_path))

# Load multiple files
# location of the pdf file/files. 
loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, fn)) for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path)]


print(loaders)

alldocument = []
vectorstore = None
for loader in loaders:

    print("Loading raw document..." + loader.file_path)
    raw_documents = loader.load()

    print("Splitting text...")
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n\n",
        chunk_size=800,
        chunk_overlap=100,
        length_function=len,
    )
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(raw_documents)
    #alldocument = alldocument + documents

    print("Creating vectorstore...")
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(documents, embeddings)

    #with open("vectorstore.pkl", "wb") as f:
    with open("vectorstore.pkl", "ab") as f:
        pickle.dump(vectorstore, f)
        f.close()
```

I am trying to load multiple files for QnA but the index only remembers the last file uploaded from a folder.

Do I need to change the structure of for loop or have another parameter with the Open Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with each iteration of the loop, you're overwriting the previous vectorstore when you create a new one. Then, when saving to "vectorstore.pkl", you're only saving the last vectorstore.

```
print("Loading data...")
pdf_folder_path = "content/"
print(os.listdir(pdf_folder_path))

# Load multiple files
loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, fn)) for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path)]

print(loaders)

all_documents = []

for loader in loaders:
    print("Loading raw document..." + loader.file_path)
    raw_documents = loader.load()

    print("Splitting text...")
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n\n",
        chunk_size=800,
        chunk_overlap=100,
        length_function=len,
    )
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(raw_documents)
    all_documents.extend(documents)

print("Creating vectorstore...")
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(all_documents, embeddings)

with open("vectorstore.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(vectorstore, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already worked with a similar kind of problem, here is the code below which will solve your problem for loading multiple files. with this code you can load even 100 GB of files because here i used multithreading and batch processing

```
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Specify the root directory where you want to search for PDF files
root_directory = "/path/to/your_data_directory"

# Set the batch size (number of files to process in each batch)
batch_size = 100

# Initialize an empty list to store loaded documents
docs = []

# Function to process a batch of PDF files
def process_pdf_batch(pdf_files):
    batch_docs = []
    for pdf_file_path in pdf_files:
        pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_file_path)
        batch_docs.extend(pdf_loader.load())
    return batch_docs

# Get the list of PDF files to process
pdf_files_to_process = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    pdf_files_to_process.extend([os.path.join(root, file) for file in files if file.lower().endswith(".pdf")])

# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor for parallel processing
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    total_files = len(pdf_files_to_process)
    processed_files = 0

    # Iterate through the PDF files in batches
    for i in range(0, total_files, batch_size):
        batch = pdf_files_to_process[i:i+batch_size]
        batch_docs = list(executor.map(process_pdf_batch, [batch]))
        for batch_result in batch_docs:
            docs.extend(batch_result)
            processed_files += len(batch)
            print(f"Processed {processed_files} / {total_files} files")
```